# How to put condition in grid view bound field?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

here my code-

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DayOfTheWeek" HeaderText="Day" ItemStyle-CssClass="Itemstyle"/>
```

from my collection entity I am getting DayOfTheWeek like 1,2...7. 1 for monday , 2 for tuesday like that. Where should I place condition so that in grid view it would display day name rather than corresponding code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Enum.Parse on the DayOfWeek enum to get the day text back in a TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day" ItemStyle-CssClass="Itemstyle">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DayOfTheWeek").ToString()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```